# How to create a file with databag's contents within a recipe

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

My issue is on how to create or parse a databag content into a file in a recipe. I want to use that file to authenticate the "wal-e" application.

This is a draft in my mine can anyone help me to see more example or add syntax's

```
 file "/etc/wal-e.d/env" do
   AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID aws['access']
   AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY aws['secret']
   WALE_S3_PREFIX "#{node['fc_db']['s3']['wale_s3_prefix']}"
 action :create
 end
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fix this by writingthe ff:

```
 aws = data_bag_item('aws', 'keys')

 template "/path/to/file/AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY" do
   owner "postgres"
   mode 0644
   source "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY.erb"
   variables(:AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY => aws['secret'])
   action :create
 end

 template "/path/to/file//AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID" do
   owner "postgres"
   mode  0644
   source "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID.erb"
   variables(:AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID => aws['access'])
   action :create
 end

 template "/path/to/file//WALE_S3_PREFIX" do
   owner "postgres"
   mode  0644
   source "WALE_S3_PREFIX.erb"
   action :create
 end
```

In here the value of the databag is parse in the file so i can use them as my application need it.

Answer (score 0):

One idea i have is the following.

```
 directory "/etc/wal-e.d" do
   owner "postgres"
   group "postgres"
   mode 00755
   action :create
 end

 directory "/etc/wal-e.d/env" do
   owner "postgres"
   group "postgres"
   mode 00755
   action :create
 end

 aws = data_bag_item('aws', 'keys')

 file "/etc/wal-e.d/env/AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY" do
   variables(:AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY => aws['secret'])
   owner "postgres"
   mode  "0644"
   action :create
 end

 file "/etc/wal-e.d/env/AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID" do
   variables(:AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID => aws['access'])
   owner "postgres"
   mode  "0644"
   action :create
 end

 file "/etc/wal-e.d/env/WALE_S3_PREFIX" do
   variables(:WALE_S3_PREFIX => "#{node['fc_db']['s3']['wale_s3_prefix']}")
   owner "postgres"
   mode  "0644"
   action :create
 end
```